# open up two tabs when someone clicks on any links on my page

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript - Need to open up open up **two** tabs when someone clicks on any links on my page.

I am a completely new when it comes to this stuff, but I understand most of it I just cant physically write it for some reason or another. Is there anyone out there that could help me? I have already looked at the open two link sections on here but none of them help. What I am trying to do is basically create a "secret page" when someone clicks ANY link on my site.. So there is a few buttons and pictures on my "thank you page" and I want that when someone clicks on ANY of the links or pictures, a NEW TAB is opened up in a NEW WINDOW and another page is opened up on the exact same thank you page.. is this possible at all? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all ahead of time!

Comment: What do you mean that you "can't physically write it"?  Do you mean you have a mental block when it comes to writing code?  If that's the case, the only way by breaking that is to write code, or at least pseudo-code, comments, etc.  Try it out.  You'd be surprised how many times you will find the answers to your questions that way.  After you give it a go, if you're still running into issues, update the question with what you did.  Cheers.

Comment: no i literally just can not write code.. i can understand it, but i can't not write it

Answer (score 0):

Form what I understand you can attach an event handler function to the link

```
function openLinkTab(){
    window.open('https://www.codexworld.com', '_blank');
    window.location = "https://www.codexworld.com";

}
```

the first line will open a new tab and second line will redirect current page to other URL